# Citation with "Republic of X"

Tags: citing, back-referencing

I have a citation in which the document is from government and some state corporations. The problem I get is that in the reference list, the name gets rearranged and loses meaning. I am using the APA format. I do not know how to fix this. Would be glad to get assisted. Here is my .bib entry.

```
@article{gokmtp2,
    title={Second Medium Term Plan (2013-2017)},
    author={Republic of X},
    journal={City: Government Printer},
    year={2013} 
}
```

On the reference list, I see this:

> of X, R. (2013). Second medium term plan (2013-2017). City:
>   Government Printer.

Instead of;

> Republic of X. (2013). Second medium term plan (2013-2017). City:
>   Government Printer.

Comment: Try `author={{Republic of X}}`.

Comment: Great! Simply the best. I guess my search was not coming any close to this earlier answer. Thanks a lot.